# SQLite: General error: 1 all VALUES must have the same number of terms

Tags: sql, sqlite

This table throws a "all VALUES must have the same number of terms" error. I had originally had indeed had allotted columns without inserting anything into them, but even after changing the obvious egregious examples of the error, the error code persisted.

```
CREATE TABLE plants (
      auto_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
      plant_id TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      plant_name TEXT NOT NULL,
      genus TEXT NOT NULL,
      description TEXT NOT NULL,
      plant_type TEXT NOT NULL,
      file_name TEXT NOT NULL,
      file_ext TEXT NOT NULL
    );
    
    
    INSERT INTO
      plants (auto_id, plant_id, plant_name, genus, description, plant_type, file_name,  file_ext)
    VALUES
      (1,'GA_13', 'Pink Muhly Grass', 'Muhlenbergia capillaris', "Muhly Grass is a perennial that takes full sun", "grass",'plant1.jpg', 'jpg'),
      (2, 'GA_01','Feather reed grass', 'Calamagrostis x acutiflora', "Feather reed grass is a perennial that takes full sun", 'grass','plant2.jpg', 'jpg'),
      (3, 'SH_32','Smooth Shadbush', 'Amelanchier laevis', "The shadbush is a perennial that can take full sun or partial shade", 'shrub','plant3.jpg', 'jpg'),
      (4, 'TR_29','Chestnut Oak', 'Quercus montana', "The chestnut oak is a perennial that takes full sun", 'tree','plant4.jpg', 'jpg'),
      (5, 'GA_20','Sideoats Grama', 'Bouteloua curtipendula is a perennial that takes full sun', 'grass','plant5.jpg', 'jpg'),
      (6, 'GR_14','Feverfew', 'Tanasetum parthenium', "Tanacetum partheniumis a perennial that takes full sun", 'groundcover','plant6.jpg', 'jpg'),
      (7, 'GA_02','Prairie Cord Grass', 'Spartina pectinata', "Spartina pectinata is not a perennial but takes partial shade or full sun",'grass', 'plant7.jpg', 'jpg'),
      (8, 'FE_01','Christmas Fern', 'Polystichum acrostichoides', "Polystichum acrostichoides is a perennial that prefers full or partial shade", 'fern','plant8.jpg', 'jpg'),
      (9, 'VI_15','Climbing Hydrangea', 'Hydrangea anomala', "Hydrangea petiolaris is a perennial that prefers full or partial shade", 'vine','plant9.jpg', 'jpg'),
      (10,'FL_03', 'New England Aster', 'Aster novae angliae', "Symphyotrichum novae-angliae is a perennial that prefers either full sun or partial shade", 'flower','plant10.jpg', 'jpg'),
      (11,'SH_34', 'Nannyberry', 'Viburnum lentago', "Viburnum lentago, the nannyberry, is a perennial that prefers either full sun or partial shade", 'shrub','plant11.jpg', 'jpg'),
      (12,'FL_30', 'Hyssop', 'Hyssopus officinalis', "Hyssopus officinalis or hyssop is a perennial shrub that prefers either full sun or partial shade", 'flower','plant12.jpg', 'jpg');
```

This table throws "near "(": syntax error". I've received this error before, but with different code, it's hard to recatch.

```
CREATE TABLE play_types (

  topo_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
  topo TEXT NOT NULL,
  plant_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(plant_id) REFERENCES plants(auto_id)

);

INSERT INTO play_types (topo_id,plant_id, topo)
VALUES
(1, 1,"edible scent sound tactile viual exploratory sensory constructive physical imaginative restorative rules bio");
(2, 2,"edible scent sound tactile viual exploratory sensory constructive physical imaginative restorative rules bio");
(3, 3,"edible scent sound tactile viual exploratory sensory constructive physical imaginative restorative rules bio");
(4, 4,"edible scent sound tactile viual exploratory sensory constructive physical imaginative restorative rules bio");
(5, 5,"edible scent sound tactile viual exploratory sensory constructive physical imaginative restorative rules bio");
(6, 6,"edible scent sound tactile viual exploratory sensory constructive physical imaginative restorative rules bio");
(7, 7,"edible scent sound tactile viual exploratory sensory constructive physical imaginative restorative rules bio");
(8, 8,"edible scent sound tactile viual exploratory sensory constructive physical imaginative restorative rules bio");
(9, 9,"edible scent sound tactile viual exploratory sensory constructive physical imaginative restorative rules bio");
(10, 10,"edible scent sound tactile viual exploratory sensory constructive physical imaginative restorative rules bio");
(11, 11,"edible scent sound tactile viual exploratory sensory constructive physical imaginative restorative rules bio");
(12, 12,"edible scent sound tactile viual exploratory sensory constructive physical imaginative restorative rules bio");
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, all inserts must have the same number of data elements as indicated in the fields list; a single check shows that the line with id 5 has less than eight.

In the second one, according to the SQLite `CREATE TABLE` [syntax](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), the column definitions must be separated by commas, so the clause constraint `FOREIGN KEY` is interpreted as a malformed column definition because the previous separating comma.